# Sitemap generation

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, seo, sitemap

I have have a few pages on my site that walk through a process of querying a custom post type (services) with it's taxonomies (locations) -- [example of custom post type (services)](http://roofsrusminnesota.com/services-we-provide/) and [example of taxonomy terms (locations)](http://roofsrusminnesota.com/areas-we-service/). I'm currently using the Google XML Sitemaps plugin.

I created a sitemap and I was anticipating to see several thousands of links based on the queryable links found in my examples. However, I essentially had one link for each of my taxonomy terms and one link for each of my custom post types.

Since the structure of my custom post type URLs will be standardized as `http://domain.com/%service%/%location%`, is there a way that i can generate a sitemap that will list all the variations?

For example, if I had 2 services and 3 taxonomy terms my generated sitemap would be something like:

```
http://domain.com/service-1/location-1
http://domain.com/service-1/location-2
http://domain.com/service-1/location-3
http://domain.com/service-2/location-1
http://domain.com/service-2/location-2
http://domain.com/service-2/location-3
```

AFAIK, nothing will do this out of the box, hence me trying to do this on my own. Maybe I'm wrong. Or maybe unnecessary. The end result is for Google to index all variations of the services and locations, as `http://domain.com/service-1/location-1` serves unique content that differs from `http://domain.com/service-1/location-2`

Any advise or information would be greatly appreciated.

** I realize that my examples will show links that have extra terminology in the URL, I'm in the process to remove those and the end result will ultimately be the format of `http://domain.com/%service%/%location%` **

Comment: Between services and locations what are terms and what are CPTs?

Comment: Have you tried using a plugin to accomplish this?

Comment: @GhostToast I've tried the Google recommended [XML Sitemap Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) and recently sought out WPMU's plugin [Infinite SEO](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wpmu-dev-seo/). I haven't used the latter, but I inquired about it would operate. [See my forum post and responses](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/does-infinite-seo-help-indexing-of-queried-internal-links#post-434920).

Comment: @Rarst i forgot to add my example links. My original post has been edited for the examples. My custom post type is called services and the related taxonomy is called locations.

Comment: I am not sure you choice of architecture is in line with WP internals. I can't remember term sub-nested in CPT in my experience, since terms are supposed to group posts, not the other way around.

Comment: It's a unique situation for this particular website and required all sorts of crazy mess to get it to work like this. however, no matter which way you go, the end result has the same URL, and that's what I'm trying to get into a sitemap